# Testing factory methods iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, unit-testing

What approach should I take to writing unit test for factories that create other objects? I've seen tests that would simply initialize two `PeriodicNotification`s and `assert` that they are equal objects. Perhaps also compare `PeriodicNotification` properties to the notification properties to test that `PeriodicNotification` parsed correctly?

They main challenge I face is knowing WHAT to test for.

Comment: Is PeriodicNotification a subclass of NSDictionary?

Comment: @danh yeah its a `typedef`

Comment: I have an option about the testing question you raise, but also an instinct to be skeptical about subclassing a dictionary in the first place, and an objection to how this method is coded.  I'll try to fit all of that into an answer.

Comment: @danh thanks, and I meant to say "no" its a `typedef`. `PeriodicNotification` is just an alias, for readability, its not actually a subclass.

Comment: Oh, can you post more fully about this class?  I'll answer the test question

Comment: Please post code, not just descriptions. It's hard to give answers without specifics.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The scope of a unit test can be quite modest, pretty much limited to the intent of the thing being tested.  For an instance-returning class method, the unit test questions is: did I get an instance of the class initialized as I expect it to be?

The test in the OP case might be:

```
PumpNotification *pumpNotification = // stub object
PeriodicNotification *periodicNotification = [PeriodicNotification nodeFromNotification: pumpNotification];

// do I have an instance?
assert([periodicNotification isMemberOfClass:[PeriodicNotification self]])
assert([node[kJSON_type] isEqual:/*value from stub object*/])
// and so on for other values
```